# Contenido de una columna de datatable no se ajusta y se sale de la pantalla

Tags: php

tengo un problema con el contenido de las columnas de un datatable porque no se me ajusta, el contenido que esta lleva es un texto largo y al momento de mostrarlo sobrepasa el tamaño de la pantalla y no permite visualizar el resto de la información.

Muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudar.

A continuacion va el codigo del script

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#grid').dataTable();
         });

</script>
```

Por otro lado el codigo que utilizo para llenar la tabla

```
<table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>Codigo</th>
                                  <th>Nombre</th>
                                  <th>Misión</th>
                                  <th>Visión</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>


                          <tbody id="container">

                           <?php
                                include_once('configuracionbd.php');

                                $query = "SELECT * FROM facultad order by id_facultad ASC";

                                $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query); 

                                $tabla = "";
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['id_facultad']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['nombre_facultad']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['mision_facultad']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['vision_facultad']."</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";

                                 }

                            ?> 
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Y asi es como de me muestra actualmente la tabla en la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para ajustar el texto del campo mision y no se me desborde la pagina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<style>
table {

  overflow-x:auto;
}
table td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 400px;
}
#grid td {
  white-space:inherit;
}
</style>
<table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>Codigo</th>
                                  <th>Nombre</th>
                                  <th>Misión</th>
                                  <th>Visión</th>
                                  <th>Visión</th>
                                  <th>Visión</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>


                          <tbody id="container">

                           
                            <tr>
                              <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                              <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                              <td>AAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaAAA</td>
                              <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                              <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                              <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>

</table>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" >
</script>
                      
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#grid').dataTable();
         });

</script>
```

utilice la funcion `style overflow-x:auto;`
aunque eso tipo de datos siempre lleva mucho texto es recomendables que utilice la funcion php

```
  $co=substr("aa112233455678899",0,10);
    echo "$co";
```

que me imprime los 10 primeras letras

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio demasiado y pude corregir mi error, de verdad gracias eso era lo que me hacia falta

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres puedes hacerlo con css, colocando table-layout en fixed  y colocando a las columnas word-wrap: break-word, algo asi:

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
table td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 400px;
}
#grid td {
  white-space:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio de mucho, si me funciono